# Android tablet with integrated kickstand

Tags: tablet

I noticed that the Lenovo Yoga tablet doesn't need a tablet cover in order to sit inclined for watching videos. It has a movable plaque on the back/edge for that.

Is there any other Android tablet model featuring something like that?

I noticed that the children don't like to carry a tablet cover (and probably not even a separate kickstand) and they prefer to use the tablet without it, even at the cost of not being able to put the table in an inclined position.

What's the correct word for that plaque, by the way? The tablet covers also have something similar on the back, you open it and then the tablet can sit inclined.

Comment: Kickstand? I'm unaware of another term to describe it.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths: A good term, indeed. If the tablets would include a kickstand on their back, it would be a very nice addition.

Comment: Do you have any other specific requirements? Screen size? Price?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths: no, I want to know what kind of tablets with integrated kickstand exist and to chose the one with the best design - the easiest to use and to carry around.

Comment: Then your question is off-topic as too broad. Its your job to find out what you want and the community can help you decide. Making lists falls on you.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths: thanks for your feedback. Indeed, I have to make lists of products for me to choose from, this is not the job of the community. In this case I would say that I want a good Android tablet with the best integrated kickstand - one that doesn't incomodate or the one that incomodate less.